# CustomEvent in IE with window.opener

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, dispatchevent, window.opener

I have a problem since few days.

On firefox my code works but not on IE. I have a window which open new window with window.open; In this new window, I do what I want and after that I would like to update a specific part on parent window.
On **parent window**, I had :

```
$(document).on('myEvent', doThis);
```

And on **the second window** I had this (I don't want to use other library like jQuery if is possible) :

```
var event = new CustomEvent("myEvent");
window.opener.document.dispatchEvent(event);
window.close();
```

On Firefox the code seems Okay but on IE it doesn't work; I've tried to add a [CustomEvent polyfill](https://github.com/d4tocchini/customevent-polyfill) (because I undestand IE doesn't implement CustomEvent), but I have new problem... IE doesn't like my :

```
window.opener.document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

How can I send an event on my "opener" (or parent) window when I finnish to do what I want in new window which was opened by my "opener" (or parent) window ?

Thx.

Comment: IE has supported [`CustomEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since IE9.

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery's trigger?

Comment: @Teemu I use IE11 and when I don't use CustomEvent polyfill, I have this error "SCRIPT445: Cet objet ne gère pas cette action" on the line "var event...."

Comment: @epascarello I've tried to use jquery like this : window.opener.$(document).trigger('myEvent'); $(document, window.opener).trigger('myEvent'); but nothing works...

Comment: First one fails Because that document is the window, not the pop up. Second one you are not referencing the document element.

Comment: @epascarello okay, the correct code is probably : $(document, window.opener.document).trigger('myEvent') ? I've tried it and the event seems not trigger in the parent window.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) says, that the `CustomEvent` _constructor_ is not supported in IE. You've to use [`createEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead in IE.

Comment: @Teemu firstly, I've tried this : var evt = document.createEvent("Event"); evt.initEvent("refreshLogCom",true,false); window.opener.document.dispatchEvent(evt); But it doesn't work ! I've just change "var evt = document..." to "var evt = window.opener.document..."; I've tried this on Firefox and IE and it works ! Do you think I can use this in prod ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the event from the parent with jQuery

```
var o = window.opener; 
o.$(o.document).trigger("myEvent");
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works !
@Teemu give me a solution which works too (without jquery). Thanks to him too.

Answer (score 0):

I use hashchange event as a workaround since IE11 doesn't fire event to window.opener typically.

```
window.opener.window.location.hash = (new Date()).getTime().toString() + '&myEvent=true';
window.close();
```

Opener side

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(){
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf('&myEvent=true') > -1) {
        // fire event on opener
    }
}
```